# NSTextField doesn't respond to keyboard input

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nstextfield

I tried to write a single-window application using Objective-C in OS X 10.8 to test some thing.  Everything works fine except that the NSTextField I created does not respond to keyboard input.  The code is as follows:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface customizedView:NSView
    +(customizedView *)aCustomizedView;  // changed method name to follow convention
@end
@implementation customizedView
    +(customizedView *)aCustomizedView{
        customizedView *newView = [[[customizedView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,400,300)] autorelease];
        NSTextField *tf = [[[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(200,150,150,50)] autorelease];
        [newView addSubview: tf positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:newView];
        return newView;
    }

    -(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)aNot{
        [NSApp terminate:self];
    }
@end

void setup(){
    NSWindow *aWindow = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,400,300) styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask backing:2 defer:NO] autorelease];
    customizedView *aView = [customizedView aCustomizedView];
    [aWindow setContentView:aView];
    [aWindow setDelegate:aView];
    [aView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [aWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSApplication *NSApp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    setup();
    [NSApp run]; [NSApp release]; [pool release];
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compile using

```
gcc -w filename.m -o tmp -framework Cocoa
```

Everything works except that I cannot input using keyboard to input into the textfield in my customized NSView.  Paste using mouse is okay.  So far I still have no ideal why this happens and I give my thanks in advance to all who read this tip sincerely.